# AWS IAM policy restriction based on Tags not giving me any access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

So I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_attribute-based-access-control.html) AWS tutorial and created this IAM policy that should give access to any dynamodb action that has these keys. But as you can see in the image attached, it tells me I do not have any permission. Also it does happen to other services, so not only dynamodb, and also I tried to hardcode the 'access-project' tag in the policy as done with the 'access-environment as you can see.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
         "Sid": "AllActionsSameProjectEnvironment",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "dynamodb:*",
         "Resource": "*",
         "Condition": {
               "StringEquals": {
                 "aws:ResourceTag/access-project": "${aws:PrincipalTag/access-project}",
                 "aws:ResourceTag/access-environment": "pre"
             },
             "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                 "aws:TagKeys": [
                     "access-project",
                     "access-environment",
                     "Name",
                     "OwnedBy"
                 ]
             },
             "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                 "aws:RequestTag/access-project": "${aws:PrincipalTag/access-project}",
                 "aws:RequestTag/access-environment": "pre"
             }
         }
     }
]
}
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW4cW.png)

Any idea why is this happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamoDB **does not support** `Authorization based on tags` as listed in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html#database_svcs).

Comment: Ok thanks! But then I suppose that in order to restrict access based on attributes for any aws service, maybe it's a better option to condition a policy based on ARN (something like " arn:aws:s3:::projectname-dev-* ") but AWS does not allow to create a policy with a wildcard resource like:
```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowFullAccessPre",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:*:*:*:projectname-pre-*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```